# Kind or kindly ways?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> When I raised my first questions about the differing uses of culture I
> was given the impression, in kindly and not so kind ways, that these
> arose mainly from the fact of an incomplete education.

This is an example from an academic book. My question is: why does the author use *kindly* but *not so kind* in relation to the word *ways*? If we omit 'not so kind', it'll be *in kindly ways*, which sounds incorrect.

Comment: Kindly can be either an adverb or an adjective.  So there is no error.

Comment: Kindly (adjective)  
kind, warm-hearted, or gentle.
*"he was a quiet, kindly man"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example is a slightly bizarre / "pathological"<sup>1</sup> one.

Strictly speaking, ***kind*** and ***kindly*** are both syntactically / semantically valid choices for *both* positions. But although I can't say exactly why, I feel the explicitly adverbial ***-ly*** form works better in the first position.

On the other hand, the "flat adverb" form works better in the "derived" expression ***not-so-kind.*** It feels a bit excessive to prepend ***not-so-*** AND append ***-ly*** to generate what's effectively a one-off derivation.

There are a dozen or so written instances of [*kindly and not so kind*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22kindly%20and%20not%20so%20kind%22) in Google Books, so obviously some writers / speakers are okay with it. But there are far more instances of the ***parallel*** construction [*kind and not so kind*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22kind%20and%20not%20so%20kind%22). Plus there are a handful of [*kindly and not so kindly*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22kindly%20and%20not%20so%20kindly%22), but that one would rarely be a good choice, even though it's got the "elegance" of parallelism.

---

TL;DR: Most writers wouldn't switch from ***kindly*** to ***not-so-kind*** in such contexts, but this is more a matter of "parallel structures" and "elegance of form" than anything to do with semantics. Either way, there's no real meaning to the choice.

---

<sup>1</sup> By "pathological" here, I mean *abnormal in properties or behaviour; not exhibiting certain properties common to almost all other examples of its class.* Which in the context of syntactic constructions means *learners* shouldn't spend an excessive amount of energy trying to understand what's going on, because little of what's learned will be applicable to other contexts.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer!